# How to save dataframe without Column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have the following DataFrame

```
+--------------------+
|                  _1|
+--------------------+
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
|{"entry": {"@type...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Each row contains valid JSON. I would live to save this so that I have a file, preferably JSON, that is just a nest of objects (these rows above). I am however getting a JSON object with

```
{"_1":"{"entry": {"@type...}
```

I would like just

```
{"entry": {"@type...}
{"entry": {"@type...}
{"entry": {"@type...}
```

Comment: Did you try passing `orient=records` i.e. `df.to_json('my_jsonfile.json', orient='records')`?

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE this is a Spark dataframe, not pandas. I need to write via SQLContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest way is *to convert to rdd and select only the values* as

```
rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row._1)
```

Then you can *convert the rdds to dataframe and save* them as

```
sqlContext.read.json(rdd).write.json('output path to json')
```

Or you can *save them directly to text json file* as

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile('path to text json file')
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thank you!! I found it easiest that I just save my List RDD with JSON to textfile, that output out the set of objects I was looking for. No need for the dataframe at all.